# Installing PEAR + PHPUnit under WINGINX

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, winginx

I need PHPUnit and according to their GitHub page I need to use PEAR to install it.

Problem is, PEAR is not installed by default on WINGINX nor does my PHP folder have a `go-pear.bat` file as mentioned here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php.

So, how do I install PEAR / PHPUnit on WINGINX??

Using Apache is not an option since I need to learn to work with NGINX.

There's little to none documentation on this due WINGINX was released only a few months ago.

[This tutorial](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/install-pear-on-windows.html) does also not work since WINGINX does NOT support `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution!! 
Since no documentation about this exists yet, and other people might come across this issue as well, I'll explain here how to fix this:

1. Download the [go-pear.phar](http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar) file and place it in the `C:\Winginx\php5\` directory
2. Open up a terminal and navigate to `C:\Winginx\php5\`
3. Type: `php go-pear.phar` and press enter
4. Follow the instructions on your screen
5. Restart NGINX
6. Open a terminal as Administrator
7. Run these 2 commands:

> ```
> pear config-set auto_discover 1
> pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
> ```

Done! You successfully installed PHPUnit

Answer (score 0):

winginx is pretty new. I am not sure if pear support is inbuilt into it as of now. You might want to check with Alexei Shabalin, the author of winginx.

Meanwhile this forum seems to find Alexei saying that pear support is currently not there.

http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.winginx.ru%2Fdiscussion%2F35%2Fpear-i-xml-rpc%2Fp1&act=url

Comment: As for not, it's not build in. Thanks for the translated version :p